# Rails Devise-JWT, how to configure devise.rb to add a dispatch_requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, devise

I'm using [devise-jwt](https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt)

The readme has the following:

dispatch_requests: "additional requests where JWT tokens should be dispatched"

Example:

```
jwt.dispatch_requests = [
                          ['POST', %r{^/dispatch_path_1$}],
                          ['GET', %r{^/dispatch_path_2$}],
                        ]
```

Based on the doc, I updated my devise.rb with the following:

```
  config.jwt do |jwt|
    jwt.secret = ENV['DEVISE_JWT_SECRET_KEY']
    jwt.expiration_time = 30.days
    jwt.dispatch_requests = [
                              ['GET', %r{^/users/confirmation.*$}]
                            ]
  end
```

With the goal of getting devise-jwt to dispatch the JWT token when a user confirms their email address via email by clicking the following link:

```
http://localhost:4400/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=16J2zDtDhjyF3vCQv2ba
```

For some reason, the above URL is not getting the JWT token dispatched in the header... Given I'm horrible at regex, I'm hoping for some help... Did I do something wrong to add the additional dispatch request in my devise config?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

If the token is in the link you click on then the token won't be in the header, it will be sent as a param called 'confirmation_token'. which you would access as:
`params[:confirmation_token]` from within the controller.

p.s. JSON web tokens are awesome, I like using them to manage state in an application so no need for session storage :D, of course this does present a slight issue when you need to access data within token on the front end.